# jquery $.each is non-blocking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("<ol>").appendTo(some_div);
$.each(map, function(i,example){
  $("<li>" + example + "</li>").appendTo(some_div)
});
$("</ol>").appendTo(some_div);
```

expected:
    `<ol><li>example1</li><li>example2</li></ol>`

actual:
    `<ol></ol><li>example1</li><li>example2</li>`

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Neal - I just "fixed" that missing quotation with an edit (almost everything was red and impossible to read). I didn't consider that that could be part of the issue. Whoops!

Comment: @McStretch lol yea. thats y i ddnt fix it lol

Comment: 4 answers with 12 votes in 6 minutes.  Jquery questions are everyone's favorite.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to append a closing `</ol>` tag.  When you append the `<ol>` tag, jQuery creates `<ol></ol>` and attaches it to the DOM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing DOM operations and not string operations. And `$("<ol>")` does already create an `OL` element and not just a string containing `<ol>`.

You need to append the `LI` elements to the newly created `OL` element:

```
var ol = $("<ol>").appendTo(some_div);
$.each(map, function(i,example){
    $("<li>" + example + "</li>").appendTo(ol);
});
```

Comment: For better browser performance, it's actually preferable to construct the entire object before doing the `appendTo`.

Answer (score 8):

You should append your `<li>` entries to your `<ol>`. Otherwise you can't know how browser is going to handle your code. Additionally, you should append `<ol></ol>` instead of separate `<ol>` and `</ol>`. jQuery's `.append` and `.appendTo` are not string operations, those are modifying page DOM tree.

```
$("<ol></ol>").appendTo(some_div);
olelement = $(some_div).find("<ol>")
$.each(map, function(i,example){
  $("<li>" + example + "</li>").appendTo(olelement);
});
```

Comment: Not very efficient to find the inserted `ol` for each `li` element. You should cache it in a variable.. Also no need to specify the closing tag, it is assumed by jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
$("<ol>").appendTo(some_div);
```

isn't simply adding an open tag as you think it is. jQuery is building an ordered list element and adding it to some_div.  Likewise, your $.each is appending list item elements to some_div, so they're ending up as siblings of the list.  You need to append the list items to the list element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$("<ol>").appendTo` creates the full `<ol></ol>` tag.  Either append the li items to the OL you've created, or create a long string and then do one append.  Append is an expensive operation, if you're going to have 10s or more list items you should do the latter.

Comment: No, `.append` is not expensive. Adding hundreds of elements using `.append` is not performance issue for any modern browser.

Comment: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841798/jquery-append-individually-or-at-once-selectors (2) http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly (3) http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/5-easy-tips-on-how-to-improve-code.html

Comment: Olli, please help me understand your comment/downvote with respect to the given links and other SO thread above.